# How to test formik yup validation error on blur?

Tags: reactjs, testing, formik, react-testing-library, yup

**I've written the following test:**

```
it('validates the first name cannot be blank', () => {
    const { findByLabelText, getByText } = render(<Profile />);
    const firstName = findByLabelText('first name');
    firstName.value = '';
    fireEvent.blur(firstName);
    const error = getByText('First name is required');
    expect(error).not.toBeNull();
  });
```

**After the test runs I get the error:**

```
Unable to find the "window" object for the given node.
```

How do I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I was setting the value of first name the wrong way. In fact, in this case there is no need to set the first name, since it defaults to ''.  The correct test implementation would be this:

```
it('validates the first name cannot be blank', async () => {
const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<Profile />);
const firstName = getByLabelText(/first name/i);

fireEvent.blur(firstName);

let error;
await waitFor(() => {
  error = getByText('First name is required');
});

expect(error).not.toBeNull();
```

});